# Can someone help me in jQuery countdown format?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have used http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html plugin for multiple countdown  on same page.

I have seconds in my anchor and I have used them by adding in current date and show the countdown to user.

```
     jQuery("#overlay").click(function () {
                        jQuery("#popup").hide();
                    });
                    $(this).children('td:eq(2)').find('a');

                    var val = parseInt($(td).text());

                    //                $(td).text('');
                    var dt = new Date();
                    dt.setSeconds(dt.getSeconds() + val);
                    console.log(dt)
                    // var dt = dat.setSeconds(val);
                    $(td).countdown({
                        until: dt, format: 'dd-HH-MM-SS', compact: true, description: '', onTick: countdowncall
                    })


 function countdowncall() {
            $('.countdown_row.countdown_amount').each(function (n) {
                $(this).text($(this).text().replace('d', 'days'));
            });
        }
```

the problem is I want   8days 13:17:12 so I relace the d with days. my code try to do this on every tick for three so this is wrong way because I call the loop every time when I need to do a small changes on simple elements.

this create the problem as "8daysdays". Do someone know how to fix it or modify the code I have already write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only **`dHMS`** format is valid in that plugin.

from [`manual`](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

> This is one or more of the following characters: 'Y' for years, 'O'
>   for months, 'W' for weeks, 'D' for days, 'H' for hours, 'M' for
>   minutes, 'S' for seconds. Use upper-case characters for required
>   fields and the corresponding lower-case characters for display only if
>   non-zero.

also there is syntax error what you have pasted.

- add `'` around DOM element
- and add radix when use `parseInt`

  ```
  var val = parseInt($('td').text(),10);
  $('td').countdown({....})
  ```

Comment: thnaks for edit the answer but can you modify my script for make it work.

Comment: I found a little hack that if you set the d to days in countdown file like compactLabels: ['y', 'm', 'w', 'days'], then it will work fine.